# Laravel and vuejs drag and drop functionality

Tags: php, laravel, axios, vuejs3

```xml
<template>
  <main class="flex">
    <HelloWorld id="board-1">
      <h1>TO DO's</h1>
      <Card draggable="true" v-for="(item, index) in items" :id="item.position">
        <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
      </Card>
    </HelloWorld>
    <HelloWorld id="board-2">
      <h1>IN PROGRESS</h1>
    </HelloWorld>
    <HelloWorld id="board-3">
      <h1>DONE</h1>
    </HelloWorld>
  </main>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import Card from './components/Card.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      position: 0,
      items: []
    }
  }, methods: {

    getCards() {
      const data = axios.get('http://192.168.3.139:8000/api/cards').then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const { data } = response.data;
        this.items = data;
      });

      // console.log(data);
      return true;
    }


  },
  mounted() {

    this.getCards();

  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Card
  }
}


</script>
<style scoped>
.logo {
  height: 6em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  will-change: filter;
  transition: filter 300ms;
}

.logo:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #646cffaa);
}

.logo.vue:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #42b883aa);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: beige;
  justify-content: center;
}

.drop {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.card {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
<template>
  <div :id="id" @dragover.prevent @drop.prevent="drop($event)" class="drop">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data() {
    return {
      localIds: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    drop(event) {
      const card_id = event.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');
      console.log(card_id);
      const card = document.getElementById(card_id);
      card.style.display = "block";
      event.target.appendChild(card);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
<template>
    <div :id="id" class="card" :draggable="draggable" @dragstart="dragStart($event)" @dragover.stop>

        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ['id', 'draggable'],
    methods: {
        dragStart(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            console.log(target);
            event.dataTransfer.setData('card_id', target.id);

            setTimeout(() => {
                target.style.display = "block";
            }, 0);
        }
    }
}

</script>

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('content')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('position')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cards');
    }
};
```

I want to perform simple and drag and drop functionality. I provide you with all file code and database schema. Please suggest to me how I can perform drag and drop using Laravel API. My simple drag and drop working fine but I want when I refresh the page it still in there where I drop cards. I provide Laravel database schema and components.

Answer (score 1):

that's a simple example that I used in my old project. I modified them for your situation:

route:

```
Route::post('cards/update', 'CardController@updatePosition');
```

controller:

```
public function updatePosition(Request $request) {
    $card = Card::find($request->id);
    if ($card) {
        $card->position = $request->position;
        $card->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Position updated successfully']);
    }
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Card not found'], 404);
}
```

Vue Component:

```
methods: {
    drop(event) {
        const card_id = event.dataTransfer.getData('card_id');
        const card = document.getElementById(card_id);
        card.style.display = "block";
        event.target.appendChild(card);

        axios.post('http://192.168.3.139:8000/cards/update', {
            id: card_id,
            position: this.id  
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

now, when you fetch data you can:

```
$cards = Card::orderBy('position')->get();
return response()->json($cards);
```

getCards:

```
methods: {
    getCards() {
        axios.get('http://192.168.3.139:8000/api/cards').then((response) => {
            this.items = response.data;

            this.items.forEach(item => {
                const board = document.getElementById(`board-${item.position}`);
                if (board) {
                    const cardElement = document.getElementById(item.id);
                    board.appendChild(cardElement);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I updated codes for you quickly. You should fix if you face any error, or improve it for yourself.